# QR Code with multiple information type

Tags: qr-code

I was wondering if there's a way to build a QR code with two kinds of data - one text data and two link URLs. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: In the future it is better to avoid yes/no questions here on Stack Overflow and ask how to do it. If pertinent, make it clear in the question that you're not even sure it can be done, but try to avoid asking "is it possible to..." and instead ask "How do I ...". The quality of the answers you'll get will be much higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. we can enter text,URL,v card on a single QR code.

Comment: Try to give some examples. not just a statement. If yes then how we can do that? A small example will be helpful

Comment: http://goqr.me/    Goto this website and add text and also URL .The QR code is generated.

Comment: Yes, we can store vCard data in QR Code also, and when you will scan that it will automatically create a new contact in your device with information autofilled. You can have a look at https://www.code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog?id=QR-Code-Generator . Which explains vCard QR Code Generator

Answer (score 1):

A QR Code is a two-dimensional barcode capable of storing ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage)) up to 2,953 bytes of binary data or 4,296 simple alphanumeric characters. The data can contain whatever you like.

The difficulty with storing *multiple* URLs in a QR-code is not that it is impossible, but that most scanner apps in smart phones and so on will only process a [single URL](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents). If you are writing the scanner app too then, yes, it it possible, otherwise it is possible but probably not advisable.

If you wish to store a single URL and some contact details you might look at storing a [vCard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) in your QR code ([here is a generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator); I have no affiliation with this project).

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed possible, but all scanner apps will not recognize all the data, and only one show one data. This [QR code generator](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/?type=murl) has a Multi URL feature that can redirect based on different parameters as time, location, device, ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, the QR code is "only" storing characters, so you could imagine having an app or any software that read the QR code content, which contains data and two URL, which split the string to open two tab.

Comment: As I was thinking ... so are you suggesting me to parse the content once I get from QR code ?